# Irreducible polynomial

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I'm asking please how to prove that  $ P(X,Y)=Y^n - R(X)$ is irreducible in $Q[X,Y]$ for any $R$ monic polynomial with $\gcd(n,\deg R)= 1$.

Comment: But...$Y^2-X^2=(Y-X)(X+Y)$

Comment: Maybe that gcd is supposed to be equal to 1?

Comment: Yes i'm sorry ,$ gcd(n,degR)=1$